# Getting C# DLL events from VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, events

I'd like to be able to access the  events in a C# DLL so I can display a Progress Bar as the
file analysis is carried out - the DLL is written by a third party using VB.Net.

Details

C# FileAnaysis.DLL

Contains a public class FileManager  which contains 2 public subs

```
public void ProgAnalysis(string fileName) 

public void ProgAnalysis(string fileName, ProgressChangedEventHandler progressChangedEventHandler, RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler runWorkerCompletedEventHandler)
```

How do I access the events generated by second sub in Vb.Net?

Comment: What events are generated by the second sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the method accepts a `ProgressChangedEventHandler` and a `RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler`, I'd wager you use delegates of these types and pass them to the method; then it will call them at the appropriate points.

For example, the following methods match the signatures of these delegate types:

```
' Matches ProgressChangedEventHandler '
Sub OnProgressChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As ProgressChangedEventArgs)
    ' Do something. '
End Sub

' Matches RunWorkerCompletedEventHandler '
Sub OnRunWorkerCompleted(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs)
    ' Do someting. '
End Sub
```

Given the above methods, you could pass them to `ProgAnalysis` like this:

```
ProgAnalysis("fileName", _
             AddressOf OnProgressChanged, _
             AddressOf OnRunWorkerCompleted)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass in methods that match those delegates. If I had to guess I'd say it's using a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) behind the scenes.

So you could do something like this.

```
void Main {
     ProgAnalysis(@"c:\test.txt", 
         delegate(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e) {
             // Do something
         },
         delegate(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e) {
             // Do something else
         });
}
```

Just guessing about the delegate signatures. Of course you could use lambdas or separate methods instead of anonymous delegates, depending on exactly what you need to do.

It doesn't matter that the library was written in VB.NET.

Comment: The wording is confusing, but I think the OP's saying the DLL was written in C# whereas he wants to *access* it in VB.NET.

Comment: @Dan Tao, you may be right. If so, your example is the way to go.